# Setting up an UIActivityIndicatorView for the UITableViewController programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a regular `UITableViewController` and a `UITableView` as its only view, and I want to have an `UIActivittyIndicatorView` in addition to the table view.

So I need a view structure like this:

```
view (UIView):
  tableView
  activityIndicatorView
```

What's the cleanest way to do it without InterfaceBuilder? I guess I need to override the `loadView:` method, but I haven't succeed doing it so far.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

UPDATE for ARC and iOS 5.0+ (I think old version needs to be removed already as we have new, better API's:)):

Add to header .h file of your `UIViewController` subclass:

```
 @property (nonatomic, weak) UIActivityIndicator *activityIndicator;
```

And override methods in .m file of your `UIViewController` subclass:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    // If you need custom color, use color property
    // activityIndicator.color = yourDesirableColor;
    [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    self.activityIndicator = activityIndicator;
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    CGSize viewBounds = self.view.bounds;
    self.activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(viewBounds), CGRectGetMidY(viewBounds));
}
```

=============================================================

non-ARC version, iOS < 5.0:

You should override  method

```
-(void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    self.activityIndicator = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray] autorelease];
    [self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicator];
    self.activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height / 2);
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
}
```

Also, add

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
```

at the header file

and

```
@synthesize activityIndicator;
```

to the .m file

Comment: Shouldn't it be `CGRect viewBounds = self.view.bounds;` instead of `CGSize viewBounds...`?