# How to load a custom progress bar at loading time

Tags: objective-c, ios7, splash-screen

I have requirement where I need to display a progress bar /activity indicator on splash screen untill my data downloading is complete in iOS 7 .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show custom (or native) activity indicator then you don't need custom splash images to show as splash screen in app (that means no need to add `Default.png | Default@2x.png (etc.)`. But yes, you'll need to add `Default-568h@2x.png` (can be add by XCode it self) if you're going to support `iPhone5` resolution too.

1. Add a `UIViewController` named "SplashViewController"
2. Add an `UIImageView` inside SplashViewController (as subview) - you can add it programmatically too. [Cocoa Touch - Adding a UIImageView programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321374/cocoa-touch-adding-a-uiimageview-programmatically) - this question may helpful.
3. Assign a background image to it (which you're showing for splash screen).
4. Add a custom (or native) activity (progress) indicator inside SplashViewController (as subview) - you can add it programmatically too. [Setting up an UIActivityIndicatorView for the UITableViewController programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841833/setting-up-an-uiactivityindicatorview-for-the-uitableviewcontroller-programmatic) - this question may helpful.
5. Customise indicator as per the need. (configure for when to start/stop?).
6. Do you downloading stuff, and when its done, just change the root view controller to the next view controller (which you want to show after downloading stuff gets done). [Programmatically change rootViewController of storyBoard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653993/programatically-change-rootviewcontroller-of-storyboard) - this question may helpful.